# Troubleshooting Site Displaying Differently in the Same Browser and OS on Different Computers

Tags: css, google-chrome

I recently received an e-mail saying my site looked weird in Chrome. Usually, this is due to people having their text zoom on the browser set to something other than 100%. I checked with the person to see if that was the case, and it was not. Here is the screen shot they sent me of this URL:

[Visual Trace Route Site](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/visual-tracert/)

[image: Broken Style]

And here is what I see:

[image: Correct Style]

They say they are running Chrome on Win 7 x64, and I am running the same. How do I go about troubleshooting this? They don't have any non-standard plug-ins installed.

Comment: Unrelated, but on Firefox 3.6.x on OS X, some of the text labels for the icons on the left side wrap to a second line -- http://i.imgur.com/E9mtB.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the chrome settings change the default font size to 13pt and you will see the problem.

The cause is that all your design resize depending on the default (100%) font size but the google map stay the same size.

Comment: +1, this is the most exact answer. Set the default font size to `13pt` and it looks exactly like the client's screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

**strong text**It could be due to window size or screen resolution. It looks like the the first screen shot has fewer pixels across. Try resizing your browser.

Edit: I tried your site and was not able to confirm my suspicion. But: the only way I was able to mess up the page was by changing the font size in Chrome (Tools/Options/Under the Hood/Font size to something **smaller** than 100%). Changing the page zoom or Windows display settings did not have any adverse effects.

Answer (score 1):

I pulled up Chrome in Win 7 x64 and your site checks out. I see the same thing you do. Just to make sure I was right on this I also tested your site in Safari, Opera, IE and Firefox. It displays perfectly fine in all of these, and even resizes properly.

My suggestion would be that it is client side for the user and thus doesn't fall into your responsibility of troubleshooting. It would be nice if you could customize every PC/MAC across the world to properly display your product but as long as it functions properly then the responsibility is on the individual to solve their problem.